# How to define a private define_singleton_method without using `send`?

Tags: ruby

I want to define a singleton method, but it needs to be private. The best I can come up with is below:

```
def initialize
  define_singleton_method(name) { ... }
  self.singleton_class.send(:private, name)
end
```

Is there a way without having to use `send` to do this?

Comment: I didn't get what you want? Are you trying to define a *private singleton method* ?

Comment: Yes, I want to define a method on the current object and for it to be private.

Comment: By default singleton methods are private. I meant no one can call it but the object on which you have defined it.

Comment: My tests say they are public. I will double check.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: That's wrong. Singleton methods are public by default: `def (foo = Object.new).bar(*) end; foo.bar # no exception`.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked `class_eval`:

```
define_singleton_method(name) { ... }
self.singleton_class.class_eval { private name }
```

Comment: In general, you should avoid using any of the `eval`s, if you can get away with less intrusive methods of reflection such as `send`, `instance_variable_get`/`_set` etc.

Comment: `eval*` gets a bad rep, but really it is only a concern, afaik, if including user input or for performance reason. In this case I think it is legit.

Comment: It is also overkill since its capabilities (evaluating arbitrary code) are simply not needed. Plain `send` is enough.